# Android Custom Buttons: Alternative to Multiple Graphics?

Tags: android, button

I think all custom button tutorials I have been able to find for Android assume you are using three images for your button: a normal image, a pressed image, and a focused image.

Instead of essentially tripling the size of a given button's resources (and creating more work for the artist/UX guy), is it possible to only supply a normal button image, and for the other states, draw some sort of overlay over the existing button by extending the Button class?

Has anybody tried doing this with any success, or is it just accepted that all custom buttons need an image for each state and that is that?

Comment: I guess you could probably do that but why risk the unnecessary complications? The size is not really an issue and your artist's work isn't quite hard.

Comment: Moreover, neither the pressed nor the focused states (nor any of the other states, like disabled) are usually just a flat color change. Focused, for example, is usually some sort of outline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the correct answer to this question is essentially what @Luksprog said in the comments... It simply isn't worth it.  Just make the extra art.

Answer (score 1):

You could by overriding the draw methods of the view in your custom button but it would be a simple process as you would have to also identify the different states yourself.